# Taking text and making it a string

Tags: java, string, text, input

I'm working on a project, just trying to get some practice programming. I have run into a bump.

I'm trying to get names from a text file that are organized something like this: `["name", "name", "name", "name"]` and convert each of the names without the punctuation marks and turn them into strings in an `ArrayList`.

Once the names are in the list I am going to sort them with another piece of code I have.  Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: I wasn't too sure how to do this if the initial String has "" in it so instead I wrote a solution with ''. If it's totally useless b/c of that sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You could [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on the `,` delimiter and [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) all `"[]` chars from the resulting array items.

This will create an `ArrayList` from the array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

**Spoiler**

```
String names = "[\"Tony Parker\", \"John Smith\", \"Michelle\", \"David\"]";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(names.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "").split(", ")));
```

- replace all unwanted chars with empty strings
- split the string on the sequence ", " into an array
- convert the array to a list (actually: create a list *view* of the array)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This shows you the basics on how to take a String of names and put each name into an arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Practice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Initialize Variables
        String names = "['Tony Parker', 'John Smith', 'Michelle', 'David']";
        ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int startingPoint = 0;


        // Replace All Unwanted Characters In String With White Space
        names = names.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", "");


        // Trim The String Down And Then Add A Comma At The End
        names.trim();
        names = names + ",";



        // For Each Comma That Is Encountered, Add The Name into The ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++)
        {
            if (names.charAt(i) == ',')
            {
                namesList.add(names.substring(startingPoint, i));
                startingPoint = i +1;
            }
        }



        // Print Out The Array List Of Names
        System.out.println(namesList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not splitting on `, `? Your solution will fail if the names contain spaces.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that. Now names like Tony Parker, work! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You really should read up on how to ask better questions here, but here are two links to get you started:

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/io/10file/10readfile.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)